# Thebibliography

Tags: bibliographies

I use Texmaker and I have a problem with `thebibliography`. If I write the following code then also the name Humph is printed on the left before the number [1].

```
\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem{Humph} James E. Humphreys.
\end{thebibliography}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable  document that shows the problem.

Comment: There are [different ways to creat a bibliography](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Creating_a_Bibliography) with LaTeX. Why are you choosing the very manual way instead of an automated solution?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that I had the package `showkeys`.

Comment: That is the default behaviour with showkeys.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
 \usepackage{showkeys}
 \renewcommand\showkeyslabelformat[1]{}
```

if you do not want the label in the bibliography